# Creating a Google Sheet on the end-user's account

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

A couple days ago, I wrote an [app](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxXiX0dW5Yn554gfPIa60uFK21E20HaADp4KqJ2IDIqFb0A3NMP/exec) that creates spreadsheets for measuring potholes. Yesterday, I had someone test that app in front of me, and from what I saw, past the other bugs, the user got some "access request" screen. Hours later, I went to Google Sheets on my account and saw that the sheet the app generated got put on my account and not theirs. I go to Gmail, and got an e-mail saying that they're requesting access to the spreadsheet.

How do I either create it under their account or make sure that they automatically have access to, and edit privilege for, it?

Comment: Does the app run as you or as the user?  Do you have their account information, meaning you are using a G Suite Business/education/non-profit account and can have the app only running for a member of the domain?

Comment: I think the app is running as me.

/* It was created under my account */

Comment: When you select **Publish->Deploy as a web app**, what is the setting under _Execute the app as:_  and also what is the setting under _Who has access to the app:_  The second is probably _Anyone_ or _Anyone even anonymous_ since I can access the front end.  I suspect the first is you as it creates new files under your account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two choices:

(a) When deploying the app, set the parameter "Execute the app as" to "User accessing the web app". Then whatever the app does will be under that user's authorization, in particular they will own any spreadsheets created by the app.

(b) Execute web app as you (the developer), but add the user as an editor by the `addEditor` method.  A straightforward attempt would be

```
function doGet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create("new spreadsheet");
  var user = Session.getActiveUser();
  ss.addEditor(user);
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("<h1>Success!</h1>");
}
```

This should work if both developer and user are in the same G Suite domain. But in general it will not work, because the app is not authorized to know user's identity: see [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getactiveuser).

A workaround is to ask the user to enter their email address (add another field to your form to collect it), and add them as an editor using it.

```
  ss.addEditor(email);
```